# Newbie want to self-study to make guitar effect/amp plugin

Tags: audio, audio-processing, self-study

I am a senior Game developer want to self-study how to create electric guitar amp/effect plugin.

I read around and managed to made a simple distortion plugin using JUCE. But because of lacking in basic knowledge, I don't 100% understand what it does so I don't know how to improve or make new plugin.

**My question is**: How should I build the foundation and deep dive further into DSP programming? What are the sources?

Thank you very much.

p/s: sorry if my English is weird.

Comment: Something to start with - https://www.amazon.com/Designing-Audio-Effect-Plugins-Theory/dp/1138591890

Comment: thank you @JuhaP, seems like the book covers topics that I want to know.